# Spark - Delay the operation performed by Spark workers on purpose

Tags: java, apache-spark

Small question regarding Spark and how to delay operations please.

The setup is very simple:

1 - query a very big database

2 - get the ID from the dataset (it is the first column)

3 - send the ID to a third party API, I have no control over, they need to do something with the ID.

Small bumps:
For step 1, the database which holds the dataset is ephemeral, the Spark job has to query the whole table, as the table will disappear. No chance to query by small batches, etc

For step 3, everything was great first. The table would contains only hundreds of identifiers.
Spark does a great job reading the table entirely and putting it into memory.

Then, need to send all the identifiers to the third party API. Sparks, with the big cluster of workers, sends the requests very quick.

When the table from step 1 contains only couple of hundreds, the third party API in step 3 could handle it fine.

Now, issue, the table contains millions of entries.
Sending them will kill the third party API as of now. All the Spark workers have a small portions of the table, small portion of the ID, and all the Spark workers sends the request with the ID to the third party API, it comes as a burst, killing the third party API.

I am using this straightforward code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SparkSession    sparkSession        = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
        final Dataset<Row>    veryBigDataSet      = sparkSession.read().jdbc("someUrl", "someTable", new Properties());
        final Dataset<String> dataSetOfIdentifier = veryBigDataSet.map((MapFunction<Row, String>) row -> row.getString(1), Encoders.STRING());
        dataSetOfIdentifier.map((MapFunction<String, String>) oneIdentifier -> sendTheIdentifierToAnAPIWithDelay(oneIdentifier), Encoders.STRING());
```

Besides me putting a horrible `Thread.sleep();` in the `sendTheIdentifierToAnAPIWithDelay`  method, does Spark have any mechanism to slow down one of its own map reduce step please?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried shrinking the number of partitions? Also, you can try sending them in bulks, using the foreachPartition method

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: I also tried reducing the number of partitions, no luck, but it is an interesting idea!, thanks!